# Replace value of 1 column with value of column 2

Tags: sql-server, replace

I have 2 columns with values like those:

```
Col1   | Col2

None   |   1
1      |   2
None   |    3
```

I just want to REPLACE the value of Column 1 if is "None" with value of Column 2

I've searches some questions like this in the Forum but couldn't find anythink like this

Hope you undertood me folks.

Comment: @Larnu you might want to add your answer or hint as an answer. New contributors might also be new at development.

Comment: Yeah i saw the documentation and some links in stackOverFlow but the part i didnt understood is this: let me explain you..
Like in the last column i have "none" how can i tell him to take the value of the column in position 3?

Comment: Third column, @OliveroSRL? We only have 2 in your question.

Comment: Sry... im little bad in english and rly rly new to developement world but i like it so much after i discovered stackOverFlow where people just help You!

Comment: No worries, @OliveroSRL. Most of us started our careers at the same spot you are today. Just remember to close out your question by marking any of the answers as accepted. It is your choice to wait for more answers to arrive before marking one of them as accepted.

Comment: Ah i didn't know that at the end i need to close the answer... If you can explain me how i will close also my previous question.. THANK YOU

Comment: Just move your mouse over an answer of your choice and there should be a way to mark an answer as accepted. Once you mark an answer as accepted, users see that your problem has been solved. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ohhh.... i've shouldn't neither say thank to you guys... lol this is so strange so i need to delete my comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace data, you should use `update`.

```
Update tablename
Set Col1 = Col2
Where Col1 = 'None';
```

If you want to write a query that will NOT change the data but will mask a NULL with different information, you could use Paul's answer or if you want to mask 'None' with different information, use Larnu's idea of using case statement:

```
select case when Col1 = 'None' then Col2 else Col1 end as Col1, Col2
from tablename;
```

If Larnu posts an answer, you might want to give Larnu the credit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the [`coalesce()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```sql
select coalesce(Col1, Col2) as Col1 from table_name
```

NOTE: If the column value is literally the string `None` and not a `NULL` datatype, then this will not work.

Comment: I am guessing they have the string literal 'None' not a NULL. But if they do in fact have NULL then this is a great way to go.

Comment: Yeah its string "None" in italian would be "Non presente" but we are in english forum so i translated it

Comment: Well given that they do have the string literal in their database this won't work.